# react navigation does't work when access another stack navigator

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux, react-navigation, expo

I have a problem with react navigation. here are my navigation codes.

## Navigation.js

```
const StartStack = createStackNavigator({
    First: EmptyScreen,
    Splash: SplashScreen 
},
{
    transitionConfig: () => fromBottom(),
});
const AppStack = createStackNavigator({
    Home: TabSet
},
{
   transitionConfig: () => fromRight(),
});
const AuthStack = createStackNavigator({ 
   SignIn: SignInScreen,
   SignUp: SignUpScreen,
   ForgotPassword: ForgotPasswordScreen
},
{
    transitionConfig: () => fromTop(),
});

export default createAppContainer(createSwitchNavigator({
   Start: StartStack,
   Auth: AuthStack,
   App: AppStack,
},
{
  initialRouteName: 'Start',
}));
```

## Tabset.js

```
import React , { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import * as navOptions from '../../navigate/navigationOptions';
import BackgroundImage from '../../components/BackgroundImage';

class TabSet extends Component{

    static navigationOptions = { headerStyle: navOptions.headerStyle};

    render(){
        return(
            <View>
                <BackgroundImage>
                </BackgroundImage>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default TabSet;
```

## NavigationOptions.js

```
export const headerStyle = {
    display:'none'
}
```

## BackgroundImage.js

```
import React , { Component } from 'react';
import { View , ImageBackground , StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import backgroundImage from '../../assets/images/backgroundImage.png';

class BackgroundImage extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <View>
                <ImageBackground 
                    source={backgroundImage} 
                    style = {styles.bgImg}
                    imageStyle = {{resizeMode : 'stretch'}}>
                        {this.props.children}
                 </ImageBackground>
            </View>
        )
     }
 }
 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  bgImg : {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%'
  }
 })
 export default BackgroundImage;
```

I create three stacks such as AppStack, StartStack, and AuthStack. Those are used in ***createAppContainer()*** function and hope to access those are as

> this.props.navigation.navigate('App')

... I am able to access

> this.props.navigation.navigate('Start')

and

> this.props.navigation.navigate('Auth')

. These two stacks are works well. Then I route from *SignIn* screen of *AuthStack* to *AppStack* using,

> this.props.navigation.navigate('App')

I see the first page of AppStack, the *Home* Screen is rendered and suddenly come back to the *AuthStack's SignIn* Screen. Then I try to navigate it again, the same thing happens again. I use redux and make the redux integrated navigation. Because i think this is a redux issue. But the issue still exists. All are works well but every time when I navigate to *AppStack* it came back to *AuthStack*. anyone can solve that please help me!

Comment: We don't really know what is happening in `TabSet`. The setup looks ok. I believe you are doing something in `TabSet` which is causing it to navigate back.

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply, i will edit my question and add the tabset component codes.

Comment: i add the backgroundImage.js, navigationOptions.js and tabset.js components

Comment: What is `I use redux and make the redux integrated navigation` about? Are you using redux with react-navigation?

Comment: yes. First time I don't use redux integration to react navigation. I use normal react navigation only. it gives the above problem. so I study this documentation to how to redux integrated with react navigation.[redux integration with react navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/redux-integration.html).but it also works only above aspect. so there is no problem with redux. this issue is another thing.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see anything wrong in the code posted above. The problem probably exists where there is a logout. You might want to investigate the places where there is a navigation back to the `AuthStack`.

Comment: I start the navigation from StartStack. then I navigate to AuthStack from a process of SplashScreen.I change that navigation to `this.props.navigation.navigate('App')`. this time it goes to AppStack's HomeScreen from SplashScreen without coming back. I can't understand why I can't navigate from AuthStack to AppStack. every time it works only two stacks.

Comment: either StartStack to AuthStack or StartStack to AppStack. If i try to go StartStack, AuthStack and finally log in to AppStack, it come back to AuthStack.

Comment: You should probably check your AuthStack then.

Comment: Clearly the navigation is working as you said `the Home Screen is rendered ` but there is probably something somewhere in your code that is navigating it back to Auth. Have you tried looking at places where you might have written `navigate("Auth")`?

Comment: yeah, i checked but i can't find any place that navigate to `Auth`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending some hours, I can understand what is the problem!

```
setInterval(()=>{
  ***...some process***
  }else{
    clearInterval(this);
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Auth');
  }
},500);
```

this code is written in the splash screen. I think the interval is cleared. but really it doesn't clear and I try to go to AppStack it returned to Auth after every 500ms. Above code is an old one and I can't remember that!